# How to enable Synapse "Managed private endpoints" with terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-synapse

I have a Synapse workspace that interacts with Storage account.
Networking for this storage account has to be "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses".

So I have to enable "Managed private endpoints" in Synapse in order to allow interactions between Synapse and Storage account.

I have the following terraform script that I used to deploy Synapse:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "synapse_metadata" {
  name               = "metadata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.stg.id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "ws" {
  name                                 = "syn-${var.global_settings.resource_prefix}"
  resource_group_name                  = var.resource_group.name
  location                             = var.resource_group.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.synapse_metadata.id

  sql_administrator_login          = random_password.sql_administrator_login.result
  sql_administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_administrator_login_password.result

  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true

  dynamic "azure_devops_repo" {
    for_each = try(var.azure_devops_repo, null) != null ? [var.azure_devops_repo] : []
    content {
      account_name    = try(azure_devops_repo.value.account_name, null)
      branch_name     = try(azure_devops_repo.value.branch_name, null)
      project_name    = try(azure_devops_repo.value.project_name, null)
      repository_name = try(azure_devops_repo.value.repository_name, null)
      root_folder     = try(azure_devops_repo.value.root_folder, null)
      tenant_id       = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    }
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = var.global_settings.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
    ]
  }
}

resource "random_password" "sql_administrator_login" {
  length           = 12
  special          = false
  min_upper        = 1
  min_lower        = 1
  numeric          = false
}

resource "random_password" "sql_administrator_login_password" {
  length           = 12
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
  min_upper        = 1
  min_lower        = 1
  min_numeric      = 1
  min_special      = 1
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_administrator_login" {
  name         = "syn-${var.global_settings.resource_prefix}-sql-administrator-login"
  value        = random_password.sql_administrator_login.result
  key_vault_id = var.vault.id
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql_administrator_login_password" {
  name         = "syn-${var.global_settings.resource_prefix}-sql-administrator-login-password"
  value        = random_password.sql_administrator_login_password.result
  key_vault_id = var.vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule" "wrkspc_firewalls" {
  for_each = {
    for item in try(var.synapse_firewall_rules, []) : item.name  => item
  }
  name                 = each.value.name
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
  start_ip_address     = each.value.start_ip
  end_ip_address       = each.value.end_ip
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "synapse_role_assignment" {
  for_each = {
    for item in try(var.synapse_user_role_assignment, []) : "${item.role_name}${item.principal_id}"  => item
  }
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
  role_name            = each.value.role_name
  principal_id         = each.value.principal_id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule.wrkspc_firewalls
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  for_each             = toset(try(var.synapse_role_assignment, []))
  scope                = var.resource_group.id
  role_definition_name = each.value
  principal_id         = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.identity[0].principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_spark_pool" "spark_pool" {
    for_each = {
    for item in try(var.spark_pool, []) : item.name => item
  }
  name                 = each.value.name
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
  node_size_family     = "MemoryOptimized"
  node_size            = "Small"
  spark_version        = 3.3

  auto_scale {
    max_node_count = 3
    min_node_count = 3
  }

  auto_pause {
    delay_in_minutes = 15
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
    ]
  }
}

# Managed Private Endpoint dans le workspace Synapse
resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint" "synapse_endpoint" {
  name                 = "endpoint-${var.global_settings.resource_prefix}"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
  target_resource_id   = azurerm_storage_account.stg.id
  subresource_name     = "blob"
}
```

What did I miss to have Synapse "Managed private endpoints" button accessible ?

I have enabled the following with terraform managed_virtual_network_enabled = true

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to enable Synapse "Managed private endpoints" with Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To set up a Synapse workspace with managed private endpoints, interacting with a Storage Account with networking enabled only from selected virtual networks and IP addresses, using Terraform, you need to ensure that all necessary resources are provisioned and correctly configured.

Before trying to achieve the configuration we need to address a few things

1. **Virtual Network & Subnet**: If you need the storage account to be accessible only from selected networks, you should also define a virtual network and a subnet where the Synapse Workspace will be deployed.
2. **Network Rules for Storage Account**: Ensure the storage account has network rules set to restrict access.
3. **Integration Runtime**: To fully enable data movement between services, a Synapse integration runtime might be needed, depending on your use case.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    # Resource Group
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "demorg-vksb"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    
    # Virtual Network
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
      name                = "demovk-vnet"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    # Subnet
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
      name                 = "demo-subnet"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
    }
    
    # Storage Account
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "stg" {
      name                     = "exvkstgacco"
      resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
      is_hns_enabled           = "true"
  
  network_rules { default_action = "Deny" virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id] }
    
    
    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "synapse_metadata" {
      name               = "metadata"
      storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.stg.id
    
    
    }
    
    
    # Random Password for SQL Administrator
    resource "random_password" "sql_administrator_login" {
      length           = 12
      special          = false
      min_upper        = 1
      min_lower        = 1
      numeric          = false
    }
    
    resource "random_password" "sql_administrator_login_password" {
      length           = 12
     
    special = true
    override_special = "_%@"
    min_upper = 1
    min_lower = 1
    min_numeric = 1
    min_special = 1
    }
    
    # Synapse Workspace
    resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "ws" {
     name = "synvk-example"
     resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
     location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
     storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.synapse_metadata.id
     sql_administrator_login = random_password.sql_administrator_login.result
     sql_administrator_login_password = random_password.sql_administrator_login_password.result
     managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
    
     identity {
     type = "SystemAssigned"
     }
    }
    
    # Managed Private Endpoint
      resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint" "synapse_endpoint" {
      name = "endpoint-storage"
      synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
      target_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.stg.id
      subresource_name = "blob"
    }
    
    # Synapse Firewall Rules
    resource "azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule" "wrkspc_firewalls" {
      for_each = var.synapse_firewall_rules
      name = each.key
      synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
      start_ip_address = each.value.start_ip
    
      end_ip_address = each.value.end_ip
    }
    
    # Synapse Role Assignments
    resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "synapse_role_assignment" {
      for_each = var.synapse_user_role_assignment
      synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
      role_name = each.value.role_name
      principal_id = each.value.principal_id
    }
    
    # Azure Role Assignments for Synapse Workspace Managed Identity
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
      for_each = toset(var.synapse_role_assignment)
      scope = azurerm_resource_group.example.id
      role_definition_name = each.value
      principal_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    # Synapse Spark Pool
    resource "azurerm_synapse_spark_pool" "spark_pool" {
      for_each = var.spark_pool
      name = each.key
      synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.ws.id
      node_size_family = each.value.node_size_family
      node_size = each.value.node_size
      spark_version = each.value.spark_version
    
      auto_scale {
       max_node_count = each.value.auto_scale_max_node_count
       min_node_count = each.value.auto_scale_min_node_count
      }
    
      auto_pause {
       delay_in_minutes = each.value.auto_pause_delay_in_minutes
      }
    }
    
    variable "spark_pool" {
      description = "Map of Spark Pool configurations"
      default = {
        "demosparkpool" = {
          node_size_family             = "MemoryOptimized"
          node_size                    = "Large"
          spark_version                = "3.1"
          auto_scale_max_node_count    = 4
          auto_scale_min_node_count    = 3
          auto_pause_delay_in_minutes  = 15
        }
      }
    }
    
    
    variable "synapse_firewall_rules" {
     description = "Map of Synapse Firewall Rules"
     type = map(object({
     start_ip = string
     end_ip = string
     }))
    }
    
    
    variable "synapse_user_role_assignment" {
     description = "Map of Synapse User Role   Assignments"
     type = map(object({
     role_name = string
     principal_id = string
     }))
    }
    
    
    variable "synapse_role_assignment" {
     description = "Set of role names for Azure   Role Assignments"
     type = set(string)
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]